# EE 2.5.5 Discussion Forum banner customization

Tags: php, forum

I'd like to have the flag banner in our Expressionengine Discussion Forum appear only [on the forum homepage](http://www.medicare-cms.com/forums).

I'm taking a college php class but we haven't gotten far enough for me to know how to write the code.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have forum, so I'm writing this as a comment rather than an actual answer. But you'd want a PHP if statement, that would read something like `<?php
$base_url = "http://www.medicare-cms.com/forums"
if($base_url == "{appropriate PHP SERVER URI}")
 include('header-main.php');
else
 include('header.php');
?>` My PHP is crap, so there's probably a missing semi-colon somewhere, but that's kind of the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
<?php
     $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     $segment = explode("/", $url);

     if ($segment[2] == ""){
       echo "<img src='/path/to/image/'>";
     }
?>
```

This says if segment #2 is equal to blank display the banner. So the banner will only show when the URL is /forum/.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `/themes/forum_themes/developer/forum_index/forum_homepage.html` file. I put a banner, for example, between these code snippets:

```
{include:top_bar}
<img src="/uploads/forum-banner.png" alt="" />
<div class="fm-header-wrapper">
```

Only the home page gets this banner. All forum themes, as near as I can tell, have this file.